# YEOMAN + BOWER: "EINVALID - Failed to read Z:\bower.json"

Tags: angularjs, json, bower, yeoman

I've just installed Yeoman, along with related dependencies (Karma, Grunt CLI, PhantomJS, Jasmine, etc.)

When running the AngularJS generator, I seem to be getting the following error:

```
bower EINVALID Failed to read Z:\bower.json
Warning: Error: Cannot find where you keep your Bower packages
Aborted due to warnings.
```

Some trouble shooting steps would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Which generator are you running?

Comment: Did you install them globally? npm install -g yo bower grunt-cli. And npm install -g generator-angular (or whatever generator  you are using). Otherwise check if all the package are on your PATH. You can do this by running 'grunt --version' in your bash.

Comment: @Leonardo I was running generator-angular

Comment: @DaanvanHulst grunt-cli and grunt both show up in Path.

Comment: Seems like the error message has changed:
Now getting just "Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt"

Comment: I think that means that grunt isn't in your package.json. Or you don't have a Grunt file in your local folder.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bad description in `bower.json` properties.
I've tried `sudo chown $user:$group` as other user on stackoverflow
suggested.
If every command does not work neither a bower clean or bower install etc.etc., it means that he reads `bower.json` but since it's not well formatted
it crashes.
It could help to place or to confront the `bower.json` content with this

```
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "1.5.8",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "./angular.js",
  "ignore": [ ],
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

This is how I Fixed after all suggestions from internet failed.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same error, when used non-latin characteres in the name:

```
{
  "name": "ЙЦЖЩШ",
  "description": "",
  ...
}
```

Just use only latin characters.